# I am addicted to masturbating, will god forgive me?

Tags: hadith, nikah, shiism, sin, masturbation

I love Allah. I am a very religious person. I love people and try to help them as much as I can, but I masturbate. I tried it one day and ever since that day I can't stop. When I first started, I didn't know it was wrong, but now it's too late. I try to do good deeds and repent and pray and fast, but the thought of letting Allah down makes me want to cry. The only time I don't do it is in Ramadan.

I am addicted to masturbating and I don't think I could ever stop. Will Allah forgive me?

Comment: I see where this is going. Instead of giving proof from sources that it's Haram, I'll say that you must stop. You may ask, "How?" Well, I know people who did this sin and they were told to slap themselves or hit the "thing", when it's hard, on the wall, head-on (I'm sorry but I have to use such language to explain). Doing this causes pain, so you will soon stop as you know pain comes from doing sin, which of course, will happen in Hellfire, if not here. May Allah save you from this sin. Don't give up, be strong friend!

Answer (score 2):

You must get married and replace masturbation with sex with your wife and don't lose hope for God's forgiveness because it's the biggest sin of all.

Comment: Marriage won’t solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Salam,
I will share a personal story as your story resonates with mine. I was 35 and I recently controlled my addiction which started at 13. Yes it is a life time. (For me someone who molested me put me into this)

People will tell you to get married. This isn’t a solution, yes I m married for long time and got kids. It’s easy to say that we masterbuate coz of no sexual contact, while that is true to very less extend but we have to find underlaying problem (ever had that flood of excitement before you do it and it goes way after your done?) that is dopamine and we r become addictive to it. Here is what has helped me

1. Never use laptop/mobile or tablet in bed. Make a rule that u do no need to use that evil thing in bed. Mobile is evil of it all. Why? Say u saw a Instagram post that make u arouse, u find similar images which excite u and make more blood flow and causes dopamine and one thing leads to another n before u know it your watching pornhub or soft sexual on website (to justify it isn’t porn). So no movie in bed or bathroom.
2. Get out of ur PJ when ur awake. Loose clothes make arousement and access easy. So no loose clothes.
3. Don’t be alone. It is annoying for introvert but what I am trying to say, if you got a small laptop, get bigger screen (this will come handy when you have kids). Keep yourself in check, open door of room so you have some accountability.
4. Know your religion. I m no where near pious as I had been lost in many ways and still in some ways but finding my ways to find myself. Know that everytime you do that, your angel on left will be writing down you deed and when they change shift. The outgoing angel will take your deeds to Allah which Allah asks that “What was my servant doing when you left him/her” and the angel will tell them. So what you want that Allah knows about you? Would you be rather be happy knowing that angel tell Allah that “Your servant was abstaining from his addiction which You do no like” or “Your servant did that what you had hated”. Remember it’s equal to Jihad if you fight your desire.
5. Marriage isn’t the solution like some prescribed. I know coz I been speak by experience. While it is a remedy but solution lies within yourself. You want to give your spouse the best time and no divided time because you will be questioned. Now some people might say, we cannot get married because we are addictive? So what? If you can restrain yourself u can change yourself and this is our test.

> May Allah help you and me and many of us who had been infested by this disease. Ameen

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu-Alaykum Brother,

Before anything, congrats on having the good conscience of feeling bad about your sins, don't ever lose that.

Next thing is, you shouldn't ever ask any human being about whether Allah will forgive you for a certain sin, nor should you judge another human by saying that Allah will/will not forgive him, Allah is the most merciful judge and I'd choose Allah over anyone to be my judge on the day of judgement. No one knows better than Allah in order to give you such an answer, that is in its very nature, a matter for him (SWT).

Having said that, it is important that you do your best to repent from your sins. Trust me, it is not meant for it to be easy, otherwise everyone would've been in Jannah. We humans are supposed to make mistakes, because that's who we are. I am not "condoning sins", but they're inevitable, the same way a baby falling while trying to walk for the first time is inevitable.

And the same way motivational videos and speakers will tell you that you need to keep fighting for your entire life in order to reach your goals, you need to keep fighting your entire life to please god. God always tests us, and no one is "safe from Fitnah and sin".

There is no shame in saying that your number 1 goal is to repent from masturbation. It shouldn't necessarily be your public goal, but it is a healthy goal as any can be.

Find support forums online, the NoFap community will definitely be some help, look it up. Also surround yourself with supportive friends who you can trust and will help you through this. Having someone know your problem will make you more willing to stop doing this sin.

Also, evacuate yourself from any environment, position, website, anything that might lead you to masturbate, and don't ever say "I'll just pass by", because that's Shaytan's #1 trick.

I think the beauty in Ramadan is that it shows us that we can. We can stop smoking, we can stop committing sins, we can stay up late to pray to god.

I pray to god you make the most out of this Ramadan knocking on our doors. Please pray for me, perhaps Allah will accept your prayer and shower me with his blessings and mercy.

Assalamu-Alaykum Brother.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make yourself busy by praying to Allah and reading Quran. I also think this might be a good trick to stop a boner. Try being in an uncomfortable situation. Try cold baths when you have
boners. When you feel cold, you might think “oh it is so cold” and then the erotic thoughts will go away and you might lose your boner. But I am not sure if the second thing I wrote about will help but I think you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Let's peruse the following mentioned points:

Firstly, Allah will forgive everyone ... but with a real repentance, not just saying Tawbah ...

Secondly, when we know that it is a great sin, hence we must do our best to stop it...

Thirdly, when we know that there are many spiritual and bodily (material) harms by doing that, consequently we must do our best to leave it, as well.

Fourthly, when you remarked that having done it in Ramadan, so it definitely demonstrate that you are the ability/will of stopping it.

Fifthly, getting married can help you, if possible. Meanwhile, getting busy by diverse sport, activities, study, etc. can make you busy, to reject it automatically.

Finally, try not to put in doubtful/dangerous status which presumably indirectly/directly make you in doing such haram practice; particularly control yourself in Cyberspace.

Good luck. توکلت علی الله

Answer (score 0):

Allah want us not to despair of his mercy as written in surah Az-zumar
Az-Zumar 39:53

قُلْ يَٰعِبَادِىَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا۟ عَلَىٰٓ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا۟ مِن رَّحْمَةِ ٱللَّهِۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ ٱلذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًاۚ إِنَّهُۥ هُوَ ٱلْغَفُورُ ٱلرَّحِيمُ

Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."

do as much good as possible to avoid sin.  hopefully Allah can help us

Answer (score 0):

I am used to Khoudarzayi Hastam, O Khada Mara Mi Bakhshad?
Shamma Bayad, double ra jaigazin, Khod Arzai, is a deed decision.
Where did Nasad return to a moral point, after the spirituality of a human being, a person with a soul, a person with a soul, a person with a soul, a moral azadi with a human being who robbed me and a path of sufficiency, Sazi and Kamal, a human being with a chalk, my grandfather facing me, a Canadian. Forbidden Khodarzayi verse verses and narrations: Khudawand dar Surah Muminoon (A/7) May Farmaid yi yi y u wijy hi man, high believer, where did you go about sexual issues khodshan ra az aloda baha ganah hafiz mi kanzha ganzand raganzad and sarfa Land, me, space, my space, there is no place for it, the pairing of sexual instincts, the goodness of the land, the condition of being overtaken by Karan Est.
Rah repentance, bass, and chanting, we can't! In my opinion of repentance, baid took ra peda kani and bashnasi, and I wanted to come to a strong opinion, but it was too slow.

Ref: https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B6%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%8A/168513